# Why is .ajax() is not working with onclick?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

**Problem:** `.ajax()` is not working with `onclick`.

When I click `Delete` this should happen:

1. delete the row in the `MySql` database.
2. hide an element with the `id="39"`.
3. redirect to `index` page.

Here is what I have so far:

`index.php` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<span class="delete_test" onclick="del_fn(39)" id="39">Delete</span>      

<script>
function del_fn(test_id){
    var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    if (x)
    {
        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'test7.php',
        data:'delete_id='+test_id,
        success:function(data) {
            if(data) {  
                document.getElementById(test_id).style.display = "none";
                window.location = 'https://www.example.com';
            }
        }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

`test7.php` file:

```
session_start();
include("connect.php");
$id_delete = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_mysqli,$_POST['delete_id']);
$db_mysqli->query("DELETE FROM table Where id = '$id_delete'");
```

Comment: does it even show the confirm dialog?

Comment: try to remove `if(data)` part? seems your test7.php isn't printing any data

Comment: check your browsers developer tools console and network tab to check for errors and to see what is happening

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the `if(data)` part.

What I would do:

- add some logic in the `test7.php` file to check whether the query executed properly or not and `echo` out `true` or `false`.
- then in the `success` handler you check `if(data == 'true')` and continue your logic there.

Here is a quick example:

- on `test7.php`:

  ```
  if(<check if query went okay here>)
  {
      echo json_encode(true);
  }
  else
  {
      echo json_encode(false);
  }
  ```
- for the `ajax` part:

  ```
  $.ajax({
      url:      path,
      type:     "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data:     data,
      cache:    false,

      success: function(response)
      {
          if(response === false)
          {
              // something went wrong with the query...
          }
          else
          {
              // query seems okay...
          }
      }
  });
  ```

One time I noticed that the redirect went ahead of the code above. But, in your case, why you need to hide the element if you are redirecting the user? Anyway, just so you can make sure, I would add this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    window.location = 'https://www.example.com';
}, 1);
```

Hope it helps!